# create new file in azure cloud shell editor

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

When we open cloudshell editor, a file is already created for us and we can save it. Once we save it , how can we create a new file? If we close the editor and open it again, then the same saved file is visible.

Restarting cloud shell or opening a new session helps but is that the only way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create new file in Azure cloud shell editor, you can run `code <filename>` to open the editor without the file explorer and create a new file. If you want to remove the file, you can run `rm -r <filename>` in the BASH.

See [Using the Azure Cloud Shell editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/using-cloud-shell-editor) for more details. Let me know if I misunderstand your question.