# How to run yaml file from Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cloud-shell, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have created a Windows Server container on an [Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli) using the Azure CLI. While trying to deploy my `aspnet core` app to the AKS cluster, I am stuck on [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli#run-the-application) of the above link. I have `sample.yaml` file on my `Windows-10` hard drive that needs to run in the [Azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) using the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f sample.yaml
```

**Question**: Where can I place the above `sample.yaml` file so I can run the above command in `Azure Cloud Shell`? I am assuming it probably has to be somewhere in my Azure storage account but where exactly it should be placed so above command can recognize its path? Currently it's giving an expected error: `the path "sample.yaml" does not exist`

Comment: Well, when you running the command you mentioned that picks file from the current directory. You are keeping somewhere else you will have to either provide relative or absolute path

Comment: @VivekKumar It does not recognize `relative or absolute path` from the hard drive either. It seems the files has to be somewhere inside Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly create a file named `sample.yaml` using `vi` or `nano` or `code sample.yaml` in the Azure could shell then copy your YAML definition.

For example, type `code sample.yaml` in the Azure Bash. It opens a `sample.yaml` file then copy YMAL content and save it. The file automatically was stored in your current working path `/home/user`.

[image]

Or, you can upload your `sample.yaml` from your local to the Azure path.

Or, you also could persistently store your file into the Azure file share. To find the Azure file share, you can type `df` command.

[image]

Comment: EXCELLENT job. Nicely explained. Your instructions worked. Your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61471072/1232087) also helped me (thank you).